# Importing data to BQ error

Tags: google-bigquery

I updated our BigQuery client to new client Google API and suddenly I started seeing this error when uploading via JSON:

```
"errors": [
{
  "reason": "invalid",
  "location": "Offset:0 / Line:1 / Column:159 / Field:q1",
  "message": "Could not convert value to string"
},
```

Job reference:

```
"jobReference": {
  "projectId": "dot-metrics",
  "jobId": "job_8e0511a40c1845cca5717daf78b605f7"
},
```

This worked before we updated our client, afterwards it just stopped working so it must be some change inside BigQuery. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a regression in a recent release that broke importing null values in json. A fix should be forthcoming.
Note if you drop the null fields (i.e. instead of "field: null" you just don't include "field" at all) it should continue to work.